# C++ boost bo data to float array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, boost-geometry

How transfer data between structures like `geometry::point` and `geometry::box` to simple float array?

Only way that i have found is `get` method. For each transfer i am need to use this?

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

typedef bg::model::point<float, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef bg::model::box<point> box;

int main()
{
    box B(point(10,10), point(20,20));
    float VertexQuad[4][2];

    VertexQuad[0][0] = bg::get<bg::min_corner, 0>(B);
    VertexQuad[0][1] = bg::get<bg::min_corner, 1>(B);
    VertexQuad[1][0] = bg::get<bg::min_corner, 0>(B);
    VertexQuad[1][1] = bg::get<bg::max_corner, 1>(B);
    VertexQuad[2][0] = bg::get<bg::max_corner, 0>(B);
    VertexQuad[2][1] = bg::get<bg::max_corner, 1>(B);
    VertexQuad[3][0] = bg::get<bg::max_corner, 0>(B);
    VertexQuad[3][1] = bg::get<bg::min_corner, 1>(B);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of doing it is not wrong, but you can simplify the process by creating a struct, with a `box`variable in it's constructor:

```
struct VertexQuad
{
    float array[2][2];

    VertexQuad(box B)
    {
      array[0][0] = bg::get<bg::min_corner, 0>(B);
      array[0][1] = bg::get<bg::min_corner, 1>(B);
      array[1][0] = bg::get<bg::max_corner, 0>(B);
      array[1][1] = bg::get<bg::max_corner, 1>(B);
    };
};
```

This way, you don't have to assign the values each time you want to use the values with an array.

EDIT: `box`only has 2 corners (2 `point`s) -> your array size should be `float array[2][2]` and you can remove the other assignments.

Comment: Understand. Thanks.